# Gerar um valor aleatório em uma faixa, excluindo uma faixa

Tags: javascript, random

Usando Javascript como fazer um intervalo com valores aleatórios com um intervalo interno excluído?

Exemplificando:

> min | | | | | |x|x|x|x|x|x| | | | | | max
>
> | | = valor aceito |x| = valor negado

Código usado:

```js
function gen(min, max, excludeMin, excludeMax){
  var value;
  while(value > excludeMin && value < excludeMax){
    value = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  }
  return value;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o código nem entra no *loop* já que o valor  inicial não atende a condição colocada. Você tem que executar a primeira vez incondicionalmente usando [`do ... while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while).

```js
console.log(gen(1, 100, 10, 20));

function gen(min, max, excludeMin, excludeMax){
  var value;
  do {
    value = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  } while(value > excludeMin && value < excludeMax)
  return value;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/RandomSubRange.js).

Eu pensei em *setar* um valor inicial que atendesse a condição, mas esse caso é complicado, nem sempre será possível.

Ainda há um problema se os parâmetros forem mandados de forma inconsistente. Então seria melhor fazer uma verificação:

```js
//seria bom verificar se recebeu null antes de usar o valor
console.log(gen(1, 100, 10, 20));

function gen(min, max, excludeMin, excludeMax){
  if (min > max || excludeMin > excludeMax) {
    return null;
  }
  var value;
  do {
    value = Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
  } while(value > excludeMin && value < excludeMax)
  return value;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/RandomSubRange2.js).

Não precisa ser exatamente esta lógica, você dá o tratamento que desejar, mas se o valor que deveria ser menor for maior que o que deveria ser maior, o *loop* sai imediatamente após o primeiro número. Pode até ser o que você deseja mas fica o alerta.

Comment: Hmm Entendi, agradeço